# Отображение фотографий в gridview

Tags: java, android, getview

Нашел пример отображения фотографий на устройстве в gridview, но почему то при закачке приложения на телефон - оно открывается и спустя некоторое время вылетает, даже не показав ни одной фотографии. Причем в эмуляторе работает и не вылетает, хотя картинок нету.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    ArrayList<String> itemList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;   
    }

    void add(String path){
        itemList.add(path); 
    }


    public int getCount() {
        return itemList.size();
    }


    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }


    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }


    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(220, 220));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        Bitmap bm = decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(itemList.get(position), 220, 220);

        imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
        return imageView;
    }

    public Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(String path, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        Bitmap bm = null;
        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options); 

        return bm;      
    }

    public int calculateInSampleSize(

        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
            if (width > height) {
                inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height / (float)reqHeight);    
            } else {
                inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth);      
            }   
        }

        return inSampleSize;    
    }

}

ImageAdapter myImageAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    myImageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
    gridview.setAdapter(myImageAdapter);

    String ExternalStorageDirectoryPath = Environment
            .getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath();

    String targetPath = ExternalStorageDirectoryPath  ;

     //     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), targetPath,      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    File targetDirector = new File(targetPath);

    File[] files = targetDirector.listFiles();
    for (File file : files){
        myImageAdapter.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
    } 
  }

}
```

Может что-то нужно прописать в манифесте ?

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.androidgridview"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS"/>
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

файл activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical">
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"/>

  </LinearLayout>
```

Вот что выдает LogCat

```
09-24 14:00:46.666: I/ActivityManager(90): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN   cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.example.androidgridview/.MainActivity} from pid 860
 09-24 14:00:46.676: W/WindowManager(90): Failure taking screenshot for (180x300) to layer 21010
 09-24 14:00:46.737: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(90): setKernelCountSet(10042, 1) failed with errno -2
09-24 14:00:46.737: D/AndroidRuntime(860): Shutting down VM
09-24 14:00:46.808: I/AndroidRuntime(860): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
09-24 14:00:46.836: D/dalvikvm(860): GC_CONCURRENT freed 101K, 77% free 483K/2048K, paused 1ms+4ms
09-24 14:00:46.836: D/jdwp(860): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
09-24 14:00:46.836: D/dalvikvm(860): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
09-24 14:00:46.926: I/WindowManager(90): createSurface Window{415d1838 Starting com.example.androidgridview paused=false}: DRAW NOW PENDING
09-24 14:00:47.696: I/WindowManager(90): createSurface Window{41533218 com.example.androidgridview/com.example.androidgridview.MainActivity paused=false}: DRAW NOW PENDING
09-24 14:00:48.026: I/ActivityManager(90): Displayed com.example.androidgridview/.MainActivity: +1s308ms
09-24 14:00:48.326: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(90): setKernelCountSet(10013, 0) failed with errno -2
09-24 14:00:48.336: W/InputManagerService(90): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@415f98c8 (uid=10013 pid=346)
09-24 14:01:25.856: D/dalvikvm(720): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 184K, 4% free 10222K/10631K, paused 62ms
09-24 14:01:25.936: D/dalvikvm(720): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 61K, 5% free 10350K/10823K, paused 56ms
09-24 14:01:25.936: I/dalvikvm-heap(720): Grow heap (frag case) to 10.375MB for 193616-byte allocation
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, понять в чем причина.

Comment: прикрепите к вопросу список ошибок

Comment: Добавьте пермишен на чтение карты памяти...

Comment: Добавил  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
Не помогло - все также открывается и спустя какое то время вылетает.

Comment: а READ_...?

Comment: Попробовал, неа ...

Comment: А зачем вы посадили `ImageAdapter` внутренним классом в ваш `Activity`?!

Answer (score 2):

Вот здесь:

```
File[] files = targetDirector.listFiles();
for (File file : files){
```

Сломается с `NPE`, если нет файлов – `listFiles()` вернет `null`. Не знаю, как эмулятор может это простить (и почему в логе нет ни следа крэша).

Возможно, на SDшке эмулятора в этой директории есть какой-нибудь файл, но он не является картинкой, поэтому ни одной картинки не показывает, но не падает (`decodeFile()` для "непонятного" файла вернет `null`, `setImageBitmap()` его спокойно схавает).
Попробуй встать дебагером на это место и посмотри, что там происходит.
По-хорошему, нужно так:

```
File[] files = targetDirector.listFiles();
if (files != null) {
    for (File file : files) {
        ...
```